# Is there a function to solve the fatal: protocol '?[200~https' is not supported

Tags: git

When i use the git to push my **repository** it will pop this problem **fatal: protocol '?[200~https' is not supported**

It's not the double quote error and ctrl + v error, i hope some hero can help me to push my repository to the remote one. Thank you

Comment: what is the URL of remote that you are pushing into? I would be willing to bet that it has the protocol set incorrectly.

Comment: `git remote -v | cat -v` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?[200~` is an artifact from "[bracketed pasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracketed-paste)". You should be safe to remove that part, but be sure to check that the rest of the URL in `git remote -v` is correct. (If you need to fix it, `git remote set-url origin $CORRECT_URL` should do the trick.)

You didn't mention your operating system or window manager/desktop environment, but most of those will have a specific key combination for "plain pasting". You may also be able to specify something in your terminal config or `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/etc file to disable bracketed paste.